# python, exponential and decimal float

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, exponential

I want to save an array with floats to at file with numpy.savetxt().
The floats have to be decimals (so non-exponential!)

The code is as follows:

```
wav = 1./w
wav = np.array(sorted(wav))
efittet = permfitfuncLD(params1[0], params1[1:],1./wav).real
eefittet = permfitfuncLD(params1[0], params1[1:],1./wav).imag
etoprint = [float(s) for s in ["%.5f" % i for i in efittet]]
eetoprint = [float(s) for s in ["%.5f" % i for i in eefittet]]
wavtoprint = [float(s) for s in ["%.5f" % i for i in wav]]
print "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "etoprint"
print etoprint
print "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "eetoprint"
print eetoprint
print "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
print "wavtoprint"
print wavtoprint
print "--------------------------------------------------------------------"
arr = np.array([wavtoprint,etoprint,eetoprint]).transpose()
print "txt to safe should contain: ", arr
```

`w` and `params` are some parameters for my function permfitfuncLD() which itself is complex.
The output is:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
etoprint
[0.50391, 0.44551, 0.37837, 0.29117, 0.19734, 0.09081, -0.03854, -0.17022, -0.325, -0.47742, -0.63656, -0.8125, -0.9728, -1.13589, -1.26684, -1.36734, -1.42736, -1.42551, -1.3545, -1.23074, -1.07199, -0.90215, -0.79518, -0.78347, -0.899, -1.14185, -1.51655, -1.87591, -2.07595, -1.89561, -1.53701, -1.56583, -2.20596, -3.38828, -4.77624, -6.39743, -8.43319, -10.62524, -13.43619, -16.55797, -20.35308, -25.49629, -31.56653, -40.21232, -51.0312, -66.09163, -90.35934, -125.69555, -188.95742]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
eetoprint
[3.51955, 3.48008, 3.44968, 3.42508, 3.41183, 3.40951, 3.4217, 3.44898, 3.49899, 3.5671, 3.6595, 3.79075, 3.94391, 4.14716, 4.3697, 4.62296, 4.92274, 5.20694, 5.49578, 5.71423, 5.85755, 5.90724, 5.8566, 5.72561, 5.58159, 5.4753, 5.48067, 5.66307, 6.04179, 6.30754, 6.06509, 5.20939, 4.3096, 3.51667, 2.98072, 2.59107, 2.28845, 2.09188, 1.9525, 1.88784, 1.89048, 1.98989, 2.20993, 2.67266, 3.45841, 4.87942, 7.80959, 13.04591, 25.27873]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
wavtoprint
[0.18787, 0.19165, 0.19527, 0.19935, 0.20327, 0.20735, 0.21196, 0.2164, 0.22142, 0.22627, 0.23134, 0.23709, 0.24265, 0.24899, 0.25514, 0.2616, 0.26897, 0.27616, 0.2844, 0.29244, 0.30096, 0.31077, 0.3204, 0.33154, 0.34253, 0.35428, 0.36794, 0.38153, 0.39742, 0.41332, 0.43054, 0.4509, 0.47147, 0.49599, 0.52099, 0.54866, 0.58214, 0.6169, 0.65956, 0.70453, 0.75608, 0.82117, 0.89206, 0.9841, 1.08769, 1.21565, 1.39322, 1.61035, 1.93745]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
txt to safe should contain:  [[  1.87870000e-01   5.03910000e-01   3.51955000e+00]
 [  1.91650000e-01   4.45510000e-01   3.48008000e+00]
 [  1.95270000e-01   3.78370000e-01   3.44968000e+00]
 [  1.99350000e-01   2.91170000e-01   3.42508000e+00]
 [  2.03270000e-01   1.97340000e-01   3.41183000e+00]
 [  2.07350000e-01   9.08100000e-02   3.40951000e+00]
 [  2.11960000e-01  -3.85400000e-02   3.42170000e+00]
 [  2.16400000e-01  -1.70220000e-01   3.44898000e+00]
 [  2.21420000e-01  -3.25000000e-01   3.49899000e+00]
 [  2.26270000e-01  -4.77420000e-01   3.56710000e+00]
 [  2.31340000e-01  -6.36560000e-01   3.65950000e+00]
 [  2.37090000e-01  -8.12500000e-01   3.79075000e+00]
 [  2.42650000e-01  -9.72800000e-01   3.94391000e+00]
 [  2.48990000e-01  -1.13589000e+00   4.14716000e+00]
 [  2.55140000e-01  -1.26684000e+00   4.36970000e+00]
 [  2.61600000e-01  -1.36734000e+00   4.62296000e+00]
 [  2.68970000e-01  -1.42736000e+00   4.92274000e+00]
 [  2.76160000e-01  -1.42551000e+00   5.20694000e+00]
 [  2.84400000e-01  -1.35450000e+00   5.49578000e+00]
 [  2.92440000e-01  -1.23074000e+00   5.71423000e+00]
 [  3.00960000e-01  -1.07199000e+00   5.85755000e+00]
 [  3.10770000e-01  -9.02150000e-01   5.90724000e+00]
 [  3.20400000e-01  -7.95180000e-01   5.85660000e+00]
 [  3.31540000e-01  -7.83470000e-01   5.72561000e+00]
 [  3.42530000e-01  -8.99000000e-01   5.58159000e+00]
 [  3.54280000e-01  -1.14185000e+00   5.47530000e+00]
 [  3.67940000e-01  -1.51655000e+00   5.48067000e+00]
 [  3.81530000e-01  -1.87591000e+00   5.66307000e+00]
 [  3.97420000e-01  -2.07595000e+00   6.04179000e+00]
 [  4.13320000e-01  -1.89561000e+00   6.30754000e+00]
 [  4.30540000e-01  -1.53701000e+00   6.06509000e+00]
 [  4.50900000e-01  -1.56583000e+00   5.20939000e+00]
 [  4.71470000e-01  -2.20596000e+00   4.30960000e+00]
 [  4.95990000e-01  -3.38828000e+00   3.51667000e+00]
 [  5.20990000e-01  -4.77624000e+00   2.98072000e+00]
 [  5.48660000e-01  -6.39743000e+00   2.59107000e+00]
 [  5.82140000e-01  -8.43319000e+00   2.28845000e+00]
 [  6.16900000e-01  -1.06252400e+01   2.09188000e+00]
 [  6.59560000e-01  -1.34361900e+01   1.95250000e+00]
 [  7.04530000e-01  -1.65579700e+01   1.88784000e+00]
 [  7.56080000e-01  -2.03530800e+01   1.89048000e+00]
 [  8.21170000e-01  -2.54962900e+01   1.98989000e+00]
 [  8.92060000e-01  -3.15665300e+01   2.20993000e+00]
 [  9.84100000e-01  -4.02123200e+01   2.67266000e+00]
 [  1.08769000e+00  -5.10312000e+01   3.45841000e+00]
 [  1.21565000e+00  -6.60916300e+01   4.87942000e+00]
 [  1.39322000e+00  -9.03593400e+01   7.80959000e+00]
 [  1.61035000e+00  -1.25695550e+02   1.30459100e+01]
 [  1.93745000e+00  -1.88957420e+02   2.52787300e+01]]
```

My Problem is, that the values have to be floats (i.e the first one should be 0.18787).
I don't understand, why the numbers in array `arr` have exponential form.

I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I fail to understand what you're tyring to do with `wavtoprint = [float(s) for s in ["%.5f" % i for i in wav]]`: `wav` is already an array of floats, why transforming them to string and back to floats ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These *are* floats. It is just another way to display floats. Numpy arrays print the floats in exponential format by default. If you need another format for storing the data in a text file, you have to use [numpy.save.savetxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html#numpy.savetxt) or do that yourself using the python formatting functions.

However, you should be aware that you're going to loose precision compared to the scientific format. The reason is that the scientific format can represent very small numbers in the same amount of digits as it can represent very high numbers. You cannot do that with the decimal representation.

Comment: In the source data, there only appears to be a precision of 6 significant digits, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: thank you! I didn't know, that the savetxt-function has a fmt parameter...!

Comment: @TimPietzcker It's not about significant digits for the decimal representation, but about digits “above” or “below” zero. If you have ``2e-40``, that's quite hard to display using decimal representation, and will likely be cut off by formatting constraints and rounded to zero.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Well, looks like he doesn't have numbers like those in his inputs either, but it's good to point this out.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in printing arrays of floats in NumPy, you can:

- Use the `fmt` parameter of the [`np.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) function. For example, if you want to print 3 columns of floats as `"%.5f"`, separated by a space, you'd use `fmt="%.5f %.5f ".5f"`.
- If you want to change the way NumPy arrays are printed on screen, you can play with the [`np.set_printoptions`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) function, using for example `np.set_printoptions(precision=5)`.

There's yet a last trick to transform an array of float in an array of strings: just use a string dtype like `dtype="|S10"` (eg, `wav.astype("|S10")`. That'll require some fiddling to find the proper size of string you want (`"|S10"` means 'up to 10 characters), as if you print something larger it'll get truncated. I wouldn't advise it in real life, but as an exercise it's harmless.